# change text of textfield from another static class

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Here is my code.

Main class

```
namespace winapp
{
public partial class Main_Form : Form
{

    //Here is textfield1

    public Main_Form()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

the other class

```
namespace winapp
{
public partial class second: Form
{
   static Main_Form main_form = new Main_Form();
   string sss = "12345";

    public second()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //I want to change the text from here
        main_form.textbox1.text = this.sss;
    }
```

Like above, I want to change the text of a textField in the main class with second class.
But my the text of textfiled does not change.

Regurd if anyone can help me.

Comment: `second` is creating a brand new `Main_Form`. That `Main_Form` isn't the one you think it is. It's not the one that gets created and called in `Program.cs's` `Main` method.

Comment: then what should I do???

Comment: Show me where you create your `second`.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What field exactly do you want to set? And from what method? Put that code in the question.

Comment: NameSpace->Folder->second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating a brand new `Main_Form`. Instead you can pass your instance of `Main_Form` to `second`:

```
public partial class Second : Form
{
    private readonly Main_Form _mainForm;

    public Second(Main_Form mainForm) {
        _mainForm = mainForm;
    }
}
```

I would then create a property on MainForm to access the textbox:

```
public ... Main_Form : Form
{
    public string MyText {
        get { return textbox1.Text; }
        set { textbox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where you create your `second` form but it would now look like this as long as you're creating it in `Main_Form`:

```
Second secondForm = new Second(this);
```

And then `second` can access `Main_Form's` MyText property which will set the textbox.

Comment: where should I place this??   public class Second(Main_Form mainForm) {
        _mainForm = mainForm;
    }

Comment: That's the constructor of the `Second` form. `_mainForm` is a private member of `Second`. So all that goes within your `Second` class. Also - just realized there was a typeo on the constructor. If you copy and pasted, do so again.